# SBJSON v2.3 surrogate chars parsing issue

Tags: ios, json, sbjson

I noticed a bug in parsing surrogate chars in SBJSON version 2.3. The issue
for me is that iOS 5 emoji chars aren't parsed correctly.

For some reasons I cannot update at this time to version 3.0 of SBJSON. Any
ideas of how to solve the issue?

Any help would be appreciated...

PS: this issue seems to be also described here:
https://github.com/stig/json-framework/issues/42

Answer (score 0):

The answer is already in your question - find a way to upgrade to the fixed version.